# Please enable MathJax previews when editing tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax, editor

MathJax works in tag wikis, but it is not enabled when editing them. Please enable MathJax in the editor preview in tag wikis.

[image: http://cs.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/157]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be fixed now, see e.g. [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/43).